# Why need the author to add override before val in a data class in order to instance an interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid).

I find `override` is added before `val route` in data class TopLevelDestination, but it's hard to understand to instance the interface `NiaNavigationDestination` in this way.

Is there other way to instance the interface `NiaNavigationDestination` ?

**Code A**

```
data class TopLevelDestination(
    override val route: String,
    override val destination: String,
    val selectedIcon: Icon,
    val unselectedIcon: Icon,
    val iconTextId: Int
) : NiaNavigationDestination


interface NiaNavigationDestination {
    val route: String
    val destination: String
}
```

Comment: They need the `override` keyword because they're overriding a parent property. The keyword does exactly what it says it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `val`s from the interface in the body of the class, but then they will not participate in `equals()`, `hashcode()`, or `copy()`. A data class only uses its constructor parameters for those functions.

Example:

```
data class TopLevelDestination(
    val selectedIcon: Icon,
    val unselectedIcon: Icon,
    val iconTextId: Int
) : NiaNavigationDestination {
    override val route: String = "something"
    override val destination: String = "something else"
}
```

In this case, it does not seem productive for something like "destination" to not be a part of `equals()` for a class that has "destination" in it's name!

It also becomes impossible to set these values to anything but a constant or something that depends on the other constructor properties.